# Java: File reading with class in. Why is there no output?

Tags: java, input, file-io

I am attempting to use the Class In (http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/javadoc/) to read a file, and I am not getting anything back. My code at the moment is:

```
public class TestingIn {

    public static void main(String [] args){

        In file = new In("textfile.txt");
        while (!file.isEmpty()) {
            String str = file.readAll();
            System.out.println(str.substring(0, 100));
            System.out.println("abc: testing the file");
        }

        System.out.println("123: testing compilation");
    }
}
```

The intention was to print the two test strings and the first 100 characters of the file textfile.txt. The code compiles fine and prints out the test string "123: testing compilation", but it doesn't print out the string "abc: testing the file" or the first 100 characters of the file (which is http://www.gutenberg.org/files/39063/39063-0.txt if that makes any difference).

I am using eclipse and I have placed textfile.txt in the top level of my project. Things I have tried so far include looking at the API linked above, google searching (which is a little tricky because of the word In being so common), searching stackoverflow, searching for file input methods (which mostly comes up with scanner), changing my code to:

```
while (!file.isEmpty()) {
    String line = file.readLine();
    if (line.contains("mountain"))
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

and of course, turning it off and on again. Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: You are specifying the file name, and not the path, in the constructor of `In` class. The Java doc does not mention where the file gets picked from. There is a method `exists()`; could you call that and check if the file is getting loaded.

Comment: System.out.println(file.exists()); returns true

Comment: Another way to read an entire file as a String, without a third-party library: `String str = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("textfile.txt")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code instead.

```
String line = null;
while ((line = file.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.contains("Mountain"))
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to want to compile unless I remove the word String from the second line: "while ((line = file.readLine()) != null) {"
and I'm still not getting any output from it.

Comment: yeah I had already updated that line.. Are you sure that your file is non-empty? And if it is non-empty does it contain the word `mountain` exactly in the same case of letters?

Comment: Yes, its defiantly the text file linked. I think its in the correct place too because if I change its name the code stops compiling.

Comment: See my update.. It contains the word `Mountain`  not `mountain`..Watch the case of `m` it is capital in `Mountain` while u were using `mountain`.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, still getting nothing.

Comment: Is this print anything if we remove the condition `if` ?? I mean just print the `line` without checking `if`  condition.

Comment: No, also the tester string doesn't print so I think we can assume the variable "file" is empty.

Comment: Yes, it is empty. or check if the path given correctly for the file. If path is given correctly fill the file with the contents that you have posted in link. You can check if file is empty before starting the loop using `System.out.println(file.isEmpty())`

Answer (score 0):

The code is pretty much fine, tough I don't know the inner workings of the class In.

Try the followings:

1) Make sure your file is readable by you, by invoking the following function: (Assuming you are using java SE 7 )

```
public static boolean isReadable(Path path)
```

2) As documentation of In class says about readAll(): "Read and return the remainder of the input as a string." It is better to rewind the file( moving the courser at the begining of the file ) by using the appropriate function given in In class.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ah, if I I change to: 
            In file = new In("textfile.txt");
        System.out.println(file.hasNextLine());    
I get "false" returned. I cant see how to return to the beginning of the file though.

Comment: File is readable? Did you provide the full path in constructor?